# Show $f_n$ and $f_{n+1}$ are coprime using divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, gcd-and-lcm

The series $f_n$ is defined by the following relation: $f_0=0,\,f_1=1$, $f_{n}=f_{n-1}+f_{n-2}$, for $n>1$. Show that $f_n$ and $f_{n+1}$ are coprime.

$$f_0=0,\,f_1=1,\,f_2=2,\,f_3=3,\,f_4=5,\,f_5=8,\,f_6=13$$

By induction:

For all $n>1$ let $P(n)$ be the assumption $\gcd(f_n,f_{n+1})=1$.

$$P(1) \ \text{is true},$$
    $$P(1): \gcd(1,1)=1 $$

$$(V.L)_{n+1}=\gcd(f_{n+1}, f_{n+2})=\gcd(f_{n+1}, f_{n+1}+f_n) \\
=\gcd(f_{n+1}, f_n)=1=(H.L)_{n+1}$$

Now how do I show that if $d\mid f_{n+1}+f_n$ and $d\mid f_{n+1}$ that $\gcd(f_{n+1}, f_n)=1$?

Many thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why the $GCD$ of any two consecutive Fibonacci numbers is $1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269956/why-the-gcd-of-any-two-consecutive-fibonacci-numbers-is-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\gcd(f_{n+1}, f_n) = \gcd (f_{n+1} - f_n , f_n ) = \gcd(f_{n-1}, f_n)$.

Comment: I can't seem to wrap my head around the divisibility logic, if |+1+  and |+1 then |+1- and | since gcd(+1,)=1 then d=1?

Comment: Do you know the rule that $ \gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a-b, b)$? If no, can you prove it? If yes, then that's what I applied, and then used the definition of $f_{n+1}$. If you continue the sequence, you eventually end up with $ \ldots = \gcd(f_2,f_1) = \gcd(1,1) = 1$.

Comment: I did not know that, thank you for bringing it to my attention and taking your valuable time to explain it!

Comment: Glad I could help. You can upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: Please strive to search for dupes before answering obvious FAQs.